# Regex - minimum and maximum of each symbol type

Tags: regex

I need to check if the string contains from 0 to 3 spaces and 16 digits. How can I do this ? All that I come up with is only for checking the sum

```
^[0-9- ]{16,19}$
```

Comment: In that order or it may be mixed? Like `  12345 889...` ?

Comment: Try [`^(?=(?:[^ ]*\ ){0,3}[^ ]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){16}[^0-9]*$)[0-9- ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/5PZXsP/1)

Comment: once your sum is validated just check whitespaces `s.match(/ {0,3}/)`

Comment: Алекс,  have you had time to check the answers? Do you need more help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually should use

```
^(?=(?:[^ ]* ){0,3}[^ ]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){16}[^0-9]*$)[0-9- ]+$
```

See the [regex demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5PZXsP/2).

Alternatively, the first space checking positive lookahead may be replaced with a negative one with reverse logic:

```
^(?!(?:[^ ]* ){4})(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){16}[^0-9]*$)[0-9- ]+$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PZXsP/3)

Both the regexps are written with the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) in mind, so as to fail the regex quicker if the lookahead pattern does not match.

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?!(?:[^ ]* ){4})` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there are 4 sequences immediately to the right of the current location, of:

  - `[^ ]*` - 0+ chars other than a space
  - - a space
- `(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){16}[^0-9]*$)` - a positive lookahead requiring that the whole string should contain 16 sequences of 0+ non-digits (`[^0-9]*`) followed with 1 digit, and then 0+ chars other than a digit up to the end of the string
- `[0-9- ]+` - matches 1+ chars that are either digits, `-` or spaces
- `$` -  end of string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex based on lookaheads:

```
^[0-9](?!(?:[0-9]* ){4})(?=(?: *[0-9]){15}$)[0-9- ]+[0-9]$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sy7IZB/6)

- `^[0-9]` and `[0-9]$` ensures we have only digits at start and end.
- `(?!(?:[0-9]* ){4})` is negative lookahead to disallow 4 spaces (thus allowing 0 to 3 whitespaces)
- `(?=(?: *[0-9]){16} *$)` is positive lookahead to allow exactly 16 digits in the input surrounded by optional spaces.

Comment: Thats great, thanks! Is it necessary to use surrounding spaces in second case ? I will validate credit card number and I think there must be no spaces at the beginning and after last digit

Comment: ok in that case check my updated answer that doesn't allow spaces at start/end.